# Is there any Google polyline map for which direction the object is going?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I have made one polyline google map for check the object location but i little bit confused from where it is going i mean fro  location A to location B OR location B to location A.I have to many coordinates so i am confused.

Can we show arrow over the polyline to describe where it is going?

Comment: Please share what have you coded so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/E45Su/355/)**
You can set the polyline icon using polyline attribute `icons`. Even you can show more than one arrow. In polyline's path array first object is Start point lat-lng and second is of end point lat-lng.

Use **offset** property of **icons** attribute to set position of arrow.

```
var lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
        scale: 4            
      };

var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [{lat: 'start point lat value', lng: 'start point lng value'}, {
                            lat: 'end point lat value',lng: 'end point lng value'}],                                    
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,                                    
                    map: map,
                    zIndex: 1000,
                    icons: [{
                          icon: lineSymbol,
                          offset: '50%'
                       },{
                          icon: lineSymbol,
                          offset: '75%'
                       },{
                          icon: lineSymbol,
                          offset: '100%'
                       }]
                 });
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Its display good but display only one arrow, i have to many coordinates so that in these case i am confused to identify where it is going.

Comment: Check fiddle demo. It's displaying 3 arrow based on icons attributes

Comment: Yes got it Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps you!! You can accept it to help other recognize the useful answer.